# What problem present in my program? Why the final output cannot be displayed

Tags: c++

The final result cannot be displayed.

/*A Teacher has five students who have taken four tests. The teacher uses the following grading scale to assign a letter grade to a student, based on the average of his or her four test scores:
90-100 A
80-89 B
70-79 C
60-69 D
0-59 F

Write a program that uses an array of string objects to hold the five students' names, an array of five characters to hold the five students' letter grades, and five arrays of four doubles each to hold each student's set of test scores. `enter code here`
The program should allow the user to enter each student's name, and his or her four test scores. It should then calculate and display each student’s average test score, and a letter grade based on the average.
Input Validation: Do not accept test scores less than zero or greater than 100.*/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SUBJECT=4,STUDENT=5;
    string name[5];
    char grade[5];
    double score[SUBJECT][STUDENT];
    double average[5];
    int i,j,k,l;

    for (k=0;k<STUDENT;k++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the name of student "<<k+1<<":"<<endl;
        getline(cin,name[k]);
    }

    for (i=0;i<STUDENT;i++)
    {
        double sum=0;

        for (j=0;j<SUBJECT;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter the test scores of subject "<<j+1<<" for "<<name[i]<<":";
            cin >> score[i][j];

            while (score[i][j] < 0||score[i][j] > 100)
            {
                cout<<"Invalid test score! Test scores can't be less than 0 or greater than 100."<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter again the test scores of subject "<<j+1<<":";
                cin >> score[i][j];
            }
            sum+=score[i][j];
            average[i]=sum / SUBJECT;
        }
    }

    cout<<setw(30)<<"Student's name"<<setw(25)<<"Average test score"<<setw(15)<<"Letter Grade"<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

    for (l=0;l<STUDENT;l++)
    {
        if (average[l]>=90)
            {
                grade[l]='A';
            }
            else if (average[l]<90 && average[l]>=80)
            {
                grade[l]='B';
            }
            else if (average[l]<80 && average[l]>=70)
            {
                grade[l]='C';
            }
            else if (average[l]<70 && average[l]>=60)
            {
                grade[l]='D';
            }
            else
            {
                grade[l]='F';
            }

            cout<<setw(30)<<name[l]<<setw(25)<<average[l]<<setw(9)<<grade[l];
    }



  return 0;
}
```

The final result name,average and grade did not be displayed before the program terminated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code :

- In this line `cin >> score[i][j];` , `i` is related to a student and `j` is related to a subject, while the declaration was score[SUBJECT][STUDENT]
- the average must be calculated after the subject loop
- you should avoid magic constants, like in name[5]
- It is better to avoid `using namespace std;`
- It is better to better encapsulate variables such as `i`, `j`, and therefore not to declare them as global

This is a working example. Note that the final output still needs to be optimised but I let you do it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

//using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SUBJECT = 4,STUDENT = 5;
    std::string name[STUDENT];
    char grade[STUDENT];
    double score[STUDENT][SUBJECT];
    double average[STUDENT];

    for (int i = 0; i < STUDENT;i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the name of student " << i+1 << " : " << std::endl;
        getline (std::cin,name[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < STUDENT; i++)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < SUBJECT; j++)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the test scores of subject "<<j+1<<" for "<<name[i]<<": ";
            std::cin >> score[i][j];

            while (score[i][j] < 0||score[i][j] > 100)
            {
                std::cout<<"Invalid test score! Test scores can't be less than 0 or greater than 100." << "\n";
                std::cout<<"Enter again the test scores of subject " << j+1 << ": ";
                std::cin >> score[i][j];
            }
            sum += score[i][j];
        }
        average[i] = sum / SUBJECT;
    }

    std::cout << std::setw(30) << "Student's name" << std::setw(25) << "Average test score" << std::setw(18) << "Letter Grade" << "\n";
    std::cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << "\n";

    for (int i = 0;i < STUDENT; i++)
    {
        if (average[i]>=90)
            {
                grade[i]='A';
            }
            else if (average[i]<90 && average[i]>=80)
            {
                grade[i]='B';
            }
            else if (average[i]<80 && average[i]>=70)
            {
                grade[i]='C';
            }
            else if (average[i]<70 && average[i]>=60)
            {
                grade[i]='D';
            }
            else
            {
                grade[i]='F';
            }

            std::cout<<std::setw(30)<<name[i]<<std::setw(25)<<average[i]<<std::setw(20)<<grade[i]<<"\n";
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Finally realise what is the mistake.

Answer (score -2):

How about adding a `<<endl` statement to the last `cout` expression. This should flush the internal buffer to the output.

Comment: added and run again but still no output for the last statement